# use python's qrcode library to embed pdf inside QR Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, qr-code, pypdf

Here's the problem statement :
I have a pdf, which is encrypted first, this encrypted pdf is then used as input to create a QRCode using python library qrcode.
When I scan the generated QR Code it shows the file name but not the actual pdf file reason being the scanned QRcode doesn't know how to get to the location of the file. For this I'd need to upload the file on cloud/ drive etc.

Is there a way by which I can embed the pdf file in the generated qrcode itself so that when the qrcode is scanned, it opens up the pdf file directly, unable to find anything so far.

Here's the sample code:

```
import qrcode
import PyPDF2
from MyQR import myqr as mq

pdfFile = open('qrco.pdf', 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile)
pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
for pageNum in range(pdfReader.numPages):
    pdfWriter.addPage(pdfReader.getPage(pageNum))

pdfWriter.encrypt('password')
resultPdf = open('encrypted_output.pdf', 'wb')
pdfWriter.write(resultPdf)
resultPdf.close()

input_data = resultPdf
#input_data = 'asd.jpg'
qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=5,                                              # defines dimensions of the qr code (LxB)
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H,      # About 30% or fewer errors can be corrected.
        box_size=5,                                             # defines dimensions of the box that contains QRcode
        border=5)
qr.add_data(input_data)
qr.make(fit=True)
img = qr.make_image(fill='black', back_color='white')
img.save('qrcode.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

[QR code capacity is quite limited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Storage), so I'm not sure it's possible to embed any PDF inside of it. But, of course, you could try to read file content and encode it to [base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) (to be a valid alphabetic string).

Comment: That's a lot of information, but looks like OP's trying to find a solution that doesn't involve references to external resources. In other words, he's asking if it's possible to fit content of a whole PDF file into a single QR-code. The answer is "no".

Comment: I think, you probably better to post that information as a separate answer here. Nobody likes to unfold comments section :)